# Is there any word mean `split text into sentences`?

Tags: word-request

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)

> In lexical analysis, tokenization is the process of breaking a stream of text up into words, phrases, symbols, or other meaningful elements called tokens.

Usually, we call a function/tool which split text into words as `tokenizer`.
So, is there any word used to denote `split text into sentences`?

Answer (score 1):

**Tokenization** is the process of splitting a string into a list of pieces or tokens. *(Words, sentences, phrases, chars or any symbol as you mentioned)*

There are **Sentence Tokenizers** and **Word Tokenizers** [[**Source**]](http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-ii-sentence-tokenize-and-word-tokenize)

A **Sentence tokenizer** can be used to find the list of sentences and **Word tokenizer** can be used to find the list of words in strings.

There's no exact term that means *"split text into sentences"* but there are other possible names for that **[Sentence boundary disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation)**, **Sentence boundary detection**, **Sentence segmentation**, and **Sentence breaking**.

Comment: OK, it is a sad news.I ask this question is because `tokenizer` is translated as `分词器 (分 split  词 word  器 tool)`  in Chinese, which make me think maybe there is a corresponding word for `split sentence tool` in English . `Sentence tokenizer` have two long words looks a little cumbersome .